# ¿Cómo quito unos corchetes de un imput?

Tags: javascript

tengo el siguiente código:

```
const joinL = (l1,l2, l = []) => {
  if (isEmpty(l1) && isEmpty(l2)) {
    return []
  } else if (isEmpty(l1)) {
    return l2
  } else if (isEmpty(l2)) {
    return l1
  } else {
      return cons(l1,l2)
  }
}


console.log(joinL([],[]))
console.log(joinL([],[1, 2]))
console.log(joinL([3,5], []))
console.log(joinL([1,2,true],["FDP",3,8,2,7]))
```

la ultima me tira lo siguiente:
[ 1, [ 3, 8, 2, 7 ], 'FDP', 3, 8, 2, 7 ]

Y quiero quitar los corchetes del medio, alguna idea? Agradezco la ayuda.

Explicación:
first: primero de una lista.
rest: el resto de la lista (lo que sigue del primero).
isEmpty: Me dice si la lista está vacía.
Cons: Construye una lista.

Answer (score 1):

La función `flat` concatena los elementos del sub-arreglo dentro del arreglo principal:

```js
function cons(arr1, arr2){
   
   // combinar los arreglos
   
  let arrayCombinado = [ 1, [ 3, 8, 2, 7 ], 'FDP', 3, 8, 2, 7 ];
 
  return arrayCombinado.flat(1);
}

console.log(cons([],[]));
```

[Referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/flat)

Comment: Excelente y simple. ¡Hoy aprendí algo nuevo!

Comment: Hola! El problema es que si yo llegase a intentar con otros valores, debo crear otro let, la idea es que sea el código quien se encargue de ser "universal" y no tener la necesidad de declarar cada entrada

Comment: Eso puedes agregarlo en el return de la función `cons`. Agregué un ejemplo.